# How does MeOH absorb into polypropylene?

Tags: water

Currently working on a project where we want to functionalize PP membranes with various monomers.  Our chemistries are aqueous and have therefore not been compatible with the membranes.  The work-around we've been using is to utilize methanol to "wet-out" the PP.

I'm curious as to why this works. There isn't too much of a difference between water and methanol. Both are low molecular weight, both are polar and protic, both are capable of hydrogen bonding. What explanation is there for methanol readily absorbing into the membranes when water cannot?

Comment: MeOH has both hydro- and lipophilic part. Hydroxyls can bind together, leaving Me to interact with polymer.

Comment: MeOH also has about 1/3 the surface tension of water: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-tension_values, and about half the viscosity, too.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The values tabulated there are about the compounds' surface against air.  Contrasting to e.g., density of a material, the values of surface tension depend on interaction of two two materials.

Comment: @Buttonwood, true for surface tension. One could measure the contact angle of MeOH and H2O drops on pp, to get valid values, but as Mithoron states, the Me part is likely to be much more atracted to PP.